# How many jumps are mandatory?

Tags: technique, training, track-and-field

Im a high school Long Jumper. And my personal best this year is 6.31 mts .

I was under the guidance of a coach now. Can anyone tell me how many days I must practice jump in pit in a week?

And I have other problems too. No matter how many strides my run way is . I land in the same place . I cant convert my speed into vertical jump. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your coach is *so* much better placed to answer this than anyone else.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - Even though I don't and I guess most won't have a good answer for this this does fall under training for a sport which is within the rules of site.

Comment: @Coach-D The community disagrees with you; meta is over there if you feel you want to discuss it more.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Coach-D isn't wrong (see `training` tag). You're right that this question is too localized as it would be more appropriate for the OP's coach, but that doesn't mean training for a sport is off-topic.